# Is there a way to make a shortcut comment the current line?

Tags: customization, shortcut, text-editor

I'm used to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> commenting the current line rather than duplicating it.

This is easy enough to change in the user preferences, however it only works when there is a highlighted selection.

Is it possible to make this work even when nothing is highlighted, so the line with the cursor is commented?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a custom operator and map the following to a shortcut.

```
bpy.ops.text.move(type='LINE_BEGIN')
bpy.ops.text.insert(text="#")
```

or if selecting the line is tiresome you can just automate the selection step then comment

```
bpy.ops.text.select_line()
bpy.ops.text.comment_toggle()
```

Creating a custom operator would look something like this

```
import bpy

class CommentLineOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = 'text.comment_line'
    bl_label = 'Comment a line'

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.text.select_line()
        bpy.ops.text.comment() >> bpy.ops.text.comment_toggle() since 2.8

        return {'FINISHED'}

bpy.utils.register_class(CommentLineOperator)
bpy.utils.unregister_class(CommentLineOperator)
```

After that, you should be able to map a shortcut easily to `text.comment_line`.

To have this load at startup, just save it with a `.py` extension and drop it into your `scripts/startup/` folder. See [How could a single Python script run when Blender is started?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2738/how-could-a-single-python-script-run-when-blender-is-started).