# Execute operators from Python at start up

Tags: python, scripting

I want to add a lamp the current scene using python on startup. I do not want to change the default scene.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.lamp_add(type='POINT', view_align=False, location=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), rotation=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), layers=(True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False))
```

It adds a point lamp at origin. Like this [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2738/how-could-a-single-python-script-run-when-blender-is-started) suggests: I have saved this file in `scripts/startup` as a `add_lamp.py`

How ever when I start blender nothing has changed. I see no lamps added.

Comment: To call an operator from an addon, this solution worked for me: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8702/attributeerror-restrictdata-object-has-no-attribute-filepath

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Background Info...

Blender intentionally prevents you from manipulating the scene at startup, this is because it is rarely useful and you end up running into issues - like loading a blend file immediately overwrite any changes you have made.

Other data such as the user preferences **can** be manipulated since this persists across different blend files.

### 1. Explicit Execution

So, if you want to do this, you can use a command line argument to run a text block in your `startup.blend`:

```
blender --python-text lamp.py
```

Or you can reference a path directly:

```
blender --python /path/to/lamp.py
```

This way you can control if the script runs before or after loading a blend file.

```
# add the lamp to any blend you open
blender example.blend --python-text lamp.py

# add the lamp, then overwrite it (not useful in this case)
blender --python-text lamp.py example.blend
```

The main drawback for this is it needs to be added to some startup script or launcher, or manually entered into the commandline each time you start blender.

---

### 2. Using Callbacks

Heres an example of a script you can place in `startup/` which adds a handler that can manipulate the scene how you like.

```
import bpy

def load_handler(dummy):
    bpy.ops.object.lamp_add(type='POINT', view_align=False, location=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), rotation=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), layers=(True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False))

bpy.app.handlers.load_post.append(load_handler)
```

This is another example which keeps the handler active but only executes on new files.

```
import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent

@persistent
def load_handler(dummy):

    # only apply to startup
    if not bpy.data.filepath:
        return

    bpy.ops.object.lamp_add(type='POINT', view_align=False, location=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), rotation=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), layers=(True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False))

bpy.app.handlers.load_post.append(load_handler)
```

This may seem overkill for such a simple task, but when you consider it gives you the ability to execute code on any newly loaded file, its quite flexible.

Comment: I want to achieve this with both pieces of code in method 2. I also tried using blender --python-text lamp.py. But it did not work.

Comment: `--python-text` relies on the textblock being available in `bpy.data.texts`, it should work as long as the text's available.

Comment: Why did neither method for the callacks work?

Comment: You ask why something failed without providing any info, Im not even sure what **neither method for the callacks** means. If something fails you need to provide a way to redo the failure, it could even be a bug, though in this case I doubt it since the features have been used/tested fairly well.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably using 2.7, the console now prints:

```
Warning! 'C:\Users\user\blender-2.70-testbuild1-win64\2.69\scripts\startup\lamps.py' 
has no register function, this is now a requirement for registerable scripts
```

You would need to add a register function to you script.

I tried this:

```
import bpy

def register():
    print("add")
```

this works, but your operator invocation leads to:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\blender-2.70-testbuild1-win64\2.69\scripts\modules\bpy\utils.py", line 160, in register_module_call
    register()
  File "C:\Users\user\blender-2.70-testbuild1-win64\2.69\scripts\startup\lamps.py", line 5, in register
    bpy.ops.objects.lamp_add(type='POINT', view_align=False, location=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), rotation=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),layers=(True, False,
 False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False))
  File "C:\Users\user\blender-2.70-testbuild1-win64\2.69\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 182, in __call__
    BPyOpsSubModOp._scene_update(context)
  File "C:\Users\user\blender-2.70-testbuild1-win64\2.69\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 148, in _scene_update
    scene = context.scene
AttributeError: '_RestrictContext' object has no attribute 'scene'
```

Comment: I opened the python file in the text editor and checked the register box. And still nothing

Comment: this script works when I run it from the text editor, why does it not work as a start up script?

Comment: @Vader I'm sorry this doesn't answer your question. Should I delete it or keep it for further reference?

Comment: keep it. We can always fix this. Maybe some devs will be able to explain this

Comment: Perhaps the operators are not available in this state of initialization.

Comment: maybe, I don't know

Comment: The other answer on the post you linked suggested to create an addon this should work, a bit more boilerplate but just copy'n paste.

Comment: I will try that now