# Invoke a Modal from Add-on Registration

Tags: python, operator

In my Add-on's `__init__.py` file I'm calling my modal operator's register function, then trying to invoke it using the following code:

`MyOperator.py`

```py
class GRAPH_OT_MyOperator(Operator):
    """My Operator"""
    bl_idname = "graph.my_operator"
    bl_label = "My Operator"

    def modal(self, context, event):
        print("Test")
        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(GRAPH_OT_MyOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(GRAPH_OT_MyOperator)
```

`__init__.py`

```py
def register():
    my_operator.register()
    bpy.ops.graph.my_operator('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

I'm getting the following error. Can anyone please tell me how I can run this modal operator after my Add-on is registered? Thank you!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.1\3.1\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 387, in enable
    mod.register()
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.1\scripts\addons\MyAddon\__init__.py", line 116, in register
    my_operator.register()
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.1\scripts\addons\MyAddon\operators\my_operator.py", line 35, in register
    bpy.ops.graph.my_operator('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.1\3.1\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 126, in __call__
    _BPyOpsSubModOp._view_layer_update(context)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.1\3.1\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 88, in _view_layer_update
    view_layer = context.view_layer
AttributeError: '_RestrictContext' object has no attribute 'view_layer'
```

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7449/execute-operators-from-python-at-start-up

Comment: If you're going to have an ongoing modal operator running in the background, please take into consideration that the autosave feature will be disabled in the meantime